# Let $X$ be any random variable. Prove that $\mathbf{E}[X^2] < \infty$ iff $\dots$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be any random variable. Prove that $\mathbf{E}[X^2] < \infty$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \, \mathbf{P}(\mid X \mid > n) < \infty$.

Comment: Because $\mathbf{E}[X^2] \approx 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n \, \mathbf{P}(\mid X \mid > n)$ for suitable interpretations of $\approx$